# C# ASP.NET How to modify CSS class via code-behind

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

So just like the title, how to modify the CSS class via code-behind?
For example the following code

```
                    <li class="active"><a href="pages-messages.html"><span class="fa fa-comments"></span> Messages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages-calendar.html"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> Calendar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages-tasks.html"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Tasks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages-content-table.html"><span class="fa fa-columns"></span> Content Table</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages-faq.html"><span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span> FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages-search.html"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Search</a></li>
```

The code above is navigation for my HTML page and the first line has li class="active", how to change it into just li and the second row which is pages-calender change it into li class="active" ?

Thanks

Comment: are you using web forms or MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using WebForms, then add `runat="server"` attributes and set unique `id` attribute for each li tag you need to modify in code-behind. 
Addition of this tags is needed  to enable programmatic access from code-behind to the HTML element.

For example:

```
<li runat="server" id="PagesMessages" class="active"><a href="pages-messages.html"><span class="fa fa-comments"></span> Messages</a></li>
<li runat="server" id="PagesCalender"><a href="pages-calendar.html"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> Calendar</a></li>
```

Then in code-behind:

```
PagesMessages.Attributes["class"] = string.Empty;
PagesCalender.Attributes["class"] = "active";
```