# Trying to change a class value from webBrowser c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control

Trying to check and uncheck a box on the webBrowser from inside Windows forms c#. I only know how to change the elementbyid value and not the elementbyclass value, if that exist... From inside the html I can change the class value from "unchecked" to "checked". But I don't know how to do it from c# webBrowser inside windows froms. Sorry my english is limited. Thanks.

what I tried

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signup-termservice").SetAttribute("unchecked", "checked");
```

if I could change the value of this class to unchecked to checked it would be fine...

```
<span class="unchecked" id="signup-termservice"></span>
```

By changing the html class it would check the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find and get the HTML Element, the change the className attribute

```
HtmlElement htmlElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signup-termservice");
if (htmlElement != null)
 {
  htmlElement.SetAttribute("ClassName", "unchecked");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[C# ASP.NET How to modify CSS class via code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44998563/10851089)

> check out this a similar question u have to figure it out in your case.But i hope u r asking for something like this